# typeahead: how to change the URL?

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

Here is my JS script

```
function fillCities(country) {
    console.log('fillCities', country);
    var url = 'ajax.php?action=getVilles&country='+country+'&ville=%QUERY';
    console.log('url', url);
    $('#city').typeahead('destroy');    
    $('#city').typeahead({
        name : 'city',    
        displayKey: 'city',
        valueKey: 'city',
        limit:10,
        cache: false,
        minLength:3,
        remote: {
            url : url
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is: when country changes, typeahead requests always the SAME url and does not change the url !

How to dynamically change the URL (the country parameter inside url) ?